# ios: Designing a shopping cart in an iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, shopping-cart

I have a design decision to make for an online ordering app. I believe this question is for a more advanced iOS/mobile e-commerce developer but I am welcoming everyone to help out.

I'm thinking to install a CMS like WordPress and add a shopping cart plugging. If i need to have mobile specific pages, then I shall create those too, also If I need to make certain PHP calls, then I need to customize the API for it too. The payment page obviously will be done using the e-commerce plugin as well. This all looks like 1-3 months of work, but i would LOVE to start on the right path. So any feedback or direction would be much appreciated.

Right now, I have to come to make a decision on how my users are going to view the products and the shopping cart from their iPhone. I'm thinking of developing an iPhone App to allow them to order online. Obviously, the app will not just be a wrapper for the page but will have other useful features in addition to the product and cart views.

So here is the question:

The app I'm thinking of is a UITabBar app composed of two views "Product" and "Shopping Cart".

**Option 1 - Native controls with individual `HTTP` posts to add products to the car, and `GET` to read from the cart.**

- The Product view implements a native `UITableView`, each item opens up a Custom `UITableViewCell` where the user can push a native button to "Add" to the cart. When the "Add" button is pushed, an `HTTP POST` is made with the product code and quantity and somehow it is written to the server's cart under one session. I still need to figure out how to obtain a session key for the cart (any ideas here would be MUCH appreciated).
- The Cart view is also implemented completely with native UI's, I haven't figured out what I need yet, but it will retrieve the Cart's current items for the users session and display it. Obviously, the user can modify items, add comments, change quantity, etc.. This sounds like a lot of headache if i need to make HTTP Posts every time something changes in the Cart to sync up with the shopping cart on the server, but never the less, the CART is completely viewed in native UIs.

**Options 2 - Product and Cart are we pages that can be viewed and manipulated using UIWebViews**

- The Product view is only a `UIWebView` that opens up a pre-made product page on the web, the page obviously has to be mobile friendly so it can look decent on the phone. When the user click on the item, it will open up the detailed product web page and the user will have a web button to click, in order to add to the cart. Of course, I can intercept these clicks using the standard `UIWebView` callbacks and examine the request URL to figure out which product was clicked.
- The cart view in the other tab (`UIWebView` as well), once clicked, will make a request to the server's cart page to display the cart under the same session. Of course, I need to figure out how to have the two UIWebViews to share the same sessions so I can get the correct cart. I still haven't dove in the code.

**Options 3 - Keep the product view and shopping cart completely on the local phone and only push out the final "order" to the server to follow through the payment pages**

- At the app start, I download the product catalog, reset the local shopping cart and simulate the cart logic in the app. Once the user is ready to checkout, i make a final call to the payment page with all the products and quantity requested. The user will then follow the page with the payments.
- Since the user can also use the web page to make orders, I would need to duplicate all the logic into the app and handle the shopping cart completely from within the app. The final "check out" also need to send the detailed product code, with "comments" to the payment page. did I mention there is a user registration process as well?

1. Which options would be best suited in terms of usability, efficiency and user experience?
2. How can I sync up the two views if i would go with option 2?
3. Are there any shopping cart solutions anyone has experience with?

Comment: Why don't you keep the cart-data stored locally and push it all at once to the server when you want to make an order?

Comment: That's also another option, however, this means that i would need to duplicate the business logic both on the web and on the app. The customer is also able to order from the web. I would prefer to keep them centralized to the web. From a programming perspective, your method is much easier, and at app launch i can download the entire catalog of products, display them, and only at the final "payment" view push the items to the cart and have the UIWebView help to make the payments by credit cart, since it will be all driven from the commerce plugins.

Comment: If you want all to be done at the server, then you should just wrap the website in a web-view and let it all happen on the server...

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party libraries,

in .h file just create object for BBBadgeBarButtonItem like this

```
BBBadgeBarButtonItem *barButton;
```

after that in your .m file set your custom button to that barButton,

```
barButton = [[BBBadgeBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomUIButton:yourBtnOutlet];
barButton.badgeValue = @"0";
barButton.badgeOriginX = 13;
barButton.badgeOriginY = -9;
```

after that after your response we can use this line of code, it will increment the count value

```
barButton.badgeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [barButton.badgeValue intValue] + 1];
```